# signature of the setContentView() method

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, setcontentview

I have this blocking error that prevents me from launching my application.
Obviously, the signature of this method requires generic types. I don't understand which ones I should use...
maybe a version error in Android Studio? The internet hasn't helped me so far...

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) as ActivityMainBinding
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        activityMainBinding.rlMainLayout.visibility = View.GONE

        getCurrentLocation()
        activityMainBinding.etGetCityName.setOnEditorActionListener( { v, actionId, KeyEvent ->
            if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
                getCityWeather(activityMainBinding.etGetCityName.text.toString())
                val view = this.currentFocus
                if(view!=null){
                    val imm:InputMethodManager=getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken,0)
                    activityMainBinding.etGetCityName.clearFocus()
                }
                true
            }else false
        } )

    }
```

the gradle file :

```xml
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'master.kotlin.weather'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "master.kotlin.weather"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
}
```

if anyone has the solution...

Comment: Post the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use this code to set the content view.**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root) 
    // REST OF THE CODE
 }
```

Feel free to ask if you need help with something  else.

Comment: it seems good, ty :)

Comment: @goujon Kindly upvote the answer if it has helped you.